# Why do I get a Syntax Error using a Button command?

Tags: python, button

In the following code which I copied and pasted from several different sources, I get the same syntax error under Button when I try to run the code. Can someone help me identify the cause? I spent quite a few hours trying to figure out the problem. I am learning...

```
# Import Required Library
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar

# Create Object
root = Tk()

# Set geometry
root.geometry("400x400")

# Add Calendar
cal = Calendar(root, selectmode = 'day', year = 2020, month = 5, day = 22)
cal.pack(pady = 20)

def grad_date():
     date.config(text = "Selected Date is: " + cal.get_date)

# Add Button and Label
Button(root, text="Get Date",command=grad_date).pack(pady=20)
# File "<stdin>", line 5
# Button(root, text="Get Date",command=grad_date).pack(pady=20)
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
date = Label(root, text = "")
date.pack(pady = 20)

# Execute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the full error message as text.

Comment: Error message added.  Thanks.

Comment: They meant the FULL error traceback

Comment: Done. Hope it is correct.

Comment: Why does it say "line 5" when there are more than 5 lines above it?

Comment: `File "<stdin>"` in your error message indicates that you're simply pasting or typing in the code at the Python interactive prompt.  That simply isn't how Python development is done - save the code in a file, then run that file.

Comment: I think you are right.  I pasted the code at the interactive prompt. Python read it one line at a time. I will try to run the code from a file. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: jasonharper seems to have provided the answer to this beginner's problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The file stdin suggests that you're trying to define the function and then continue and define the button outside of the function in the same input line of stdin, you need to press enter once more to close out the function input before entering the button

```
>>>def grad_date():  <presses enter>
...     date.config(text = "Selected Date is: " + cal.get_date). <presses enter>
...<press enter once more here>
>>>Button(root, text="Get D...
```